# My View Sets its frame itself

Tags: ios

I have created a view using storyboard and i want to move it 20pixels when it is ios 6(guess why:D).

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
   if( SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0") )
   {
       self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height );
   }
}
```

This code doesn't work at here but if I put it in a function that is called later it does for the first time but then resets itself to default height.

Why this frame change and how can I make sure it stays as it is?

Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your view reverts to its default height is most likely due to auto layout. If you change frames directly with auto layout turned on, then when anything causes the view to redraw itself, the objects will revert to the frames determined by their constraints. So, you should change the size or position of a view using their constraints rather than setting frames (or turn off auto layout).

The reason the code you posted doesn't work in awakeFromNib is because of what I said above. The view hasn't been loaded or drawn yet at that point, so it reverts to its constraint defined frames before you even see it.